# How to extract Json values from KStream <String,JsonObject>

Tags: json, apache-kafka-streams

I'm receiving Json message from input topic (employee_addition) topic, as key value pair, key being Department name and value being employee information in Json.

I want to extract just employee information and store them into employeedata class

Key is HR

Format of the Json

```
{
"version": "v7",
"employee-data": {
"firstName": "John",
"middleName": ""
"LastName": "Michael",
"gender": "Male"
"Location": "Toronto"
"DateOfBirth": "02-Mar-1985",
"DateOfJoining": "02-May-2010",
"emailAddress": 'john.michael@ccc.com"
}
```

this is the class

```
public class EmployeeHandler {
 private static String employeeinfo;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {   
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, JsonObject> employeeStream = builder.stream("employee_addition"); 
            employeeStream.foreach((key,value) -> {
             employeeInfo = value;
             System.out.println( key + " --->" + value);
         }); 
    }

}
```

with the above method, its not getting into foreach loop itself,
How to get the value alone from KStream ?

Comment: To start processing, you need to create a `KafkaStreams` client and call `#start()`: cf https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/write-streams.html#using-kstreams-within-your-application-code

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax, I added the props and started the stream  but still not able to get into the For loop and extract the Json Values

Comment: Hard to tell. If there is no error in the logs and if there is data, it should work. Did you try to follow the quickstart step by step? Does the quickstart work for you?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, Yes, I followed the steps, I dont get any errors, it just that it skips the for loop , though i see the messages in output topic when i transform the value to upper case and push it to output topics, its strange that i'm not able to extract or iterate thro the values when i read from input topic

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpoint? Maybe the print is just not flushed? What happens if you add `System.out.flush()` ?

Comment: Can you update your question with the source code that's not working?